# How can I automate / schedule a WCF service call hosted in IIS?

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7, powershell

I've got an extraordinarily simple service contract for a service that manages its own data import, similar to this:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Company.Services.Domain.Contract
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "ImportService", Namespace = "http://services.company.org/")]
    public interface IImportService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ImportResponse ImportData();
    }
}
```

I'd like to set up a scheduled task or something similar to execute this call on a daily basis.  I know that I could write a console application and create a proxy via svcutil.  **But is there a way to configure this in IIS natively (maybe an IIS extension)?  Or could I achieve something simple and elegant with PowerShell?**

Just wondering what my options are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use cURL (Windows and 'nix versions available): http://curl.haxx.se/

Set your scheduled task to invoke curl.exe with parameters appropriate to make a request to your web service's URL:

```
curl -o importResponse.txt http://services.company.org/ImportService.svc/ImportData
```

The -o will drop the response into a text file of the given name. Other configuration options can be found in the manual: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

EDIT: This assumes that you're exposing a web service and GET (rather than POST or SOAP). If you're exposing a SOAP service it should still be fairly trivial because you're not passing any parameters.

```
curl --request POST --header 'Content-type: text/xml' --output importResponse.txt --data <SOAP/> http://services.company.org/ImportService.svc/ImportData
```

Alternatively, as you're using WCF you can expose your service as both a SOAP service and a RESTful web service simultaneously, by adding some configuration to your app's web.config: a webHttpBinding, a service endpoint, and an endpointBehavior, as per: http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/archive/2008/10/08/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.aspx

Comment: Cool utility!  Wouldn't I have to snag the SOAP body though and post that as a parameter?

Comment: Ah, yes, if you're using SOAP it's a little less simple. I've updated the answer appropriately.

Comment: I attempted the updated curl line but it didn't appear to do the trick...I'm sure I could find the SOAP generated in a normal call and plug it in but I'll have to play with it some more.  Going to see if that RESTful way works as well.

Comment: Making the method invokable through a GET will make it extraordinarily simple to automate.  Just verified it working thanks to that blog entry.

Answer (score 4):

You can have an IIS-hosted application that uses [IIS auto-start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260.aspx), assuming you are running at least version 7.5 of IIS. The auto-start does not run on a timer, but will help guarantee that your application is always running. After IIS starts the application, your code can start a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) to call the WCF service each day.

The timer would, of course, be implemented in code. Examples of simple timer implementations include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c/3243354#3243354), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx#exampleToggle), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091710/c-timer-or-thread-sleep/1091753#1091753).

If you are using ASP.NET then put the timer start code in the `Application_Start` method in the global.asax file of the auto-started application.

Comment: Auto-start is a sweet feature for keeping the service highly available...not sure how it would call a specific service method at a given time of day though.  App start would only give it to me once as it fires up, right?

Comment: You would have a recurring timer in your code that is started by App Start. the IIS auto-start would ensure that it's always running. I edited my answer to include links to some sample timer implementations in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

Check ou New-WebServiceProxy. It's very useful, you point it at the url and it loads the web ervice. You can pipe it to Get-Member to see whats available as well.

Matt

EDIT: example now I'm not on my phone :-)

```
# url for the service
$url = "http://services.company.org/ImportService"             

# Create the service - using default credentials         
$service = New-WebServiceProxy $Url -UseDefaultCredentials

# explore the service
$service | gm
```

for more information check out the PowerShell help

```
help New-WebServiceProxy
```