# Calling a function periodically c#

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I am sending mails from my codes, for some activities.

But some mails may fail due to some or other reason.

I am keeping details of all such failed mails in a table.

Now my plan is to periodically check that table and **resend mails** if the table contain failed mails.

Or in other words,I want to call a method SentFailedMails() **in every 12 hours**.

How can I do this is c#

My application is a WCF service,Hosted on IIS

Comment: Is your application a service which runs 24/7?

Comment: Use the windows taskscheduler and run a custom exe.

Comment: use windows services or job

Comment: I don't think there is such things in mvc.It's better you write windows service for this task and then install on your webserver to resend email

Comment: Perhaps.  Then again, the last thing the world wants is _another_ Windows Service with a built-in scheduling component.  Consider using the standard _Task Scheduler_ as rene mentioned instead and have it run  your regular non-service .EXE.  Plus it's kinder to puppies

Comment: My application is WCF service

Comment: @KuttanSujith Great! What _sort_ of WCF service? Where is it hosted?  _IIS? WinForms? WPF? Custom host .exe?_ A WCF Service _inside a Windows Service_?

Comment: You can mark the temporarily failed emails in a table in database. Now you can write another windows service which can have a timer to resend your emails. Or you can write a simple console application for re-sending emails and call this application from Windows Task Schedular

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6899188/706456)

Comment: can you use `httpmodule` ? I mean global.asax file ?

Comment: Yes I can use global.asax

Comment: Please explain what can i do if i can use  global.asax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a very simple console application that do the task (move your SentFailedMails() method to this application and execute it on run).

Place the exe file for the console application in a folder of your server.

Use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule the exe file execution for every 12 hours or on any specific time.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler is a ready to use thing from windows. You can set it to execute a program in specific times of the day. Non developer can use it. 
[link](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)

Workflow foundation is more towards developing your own scheduler. I think.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a scheduler like [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a threading.timer and set it to 12:00:00 then give it your mail method to execute . Don't forget about the dispatcher to change thread though.