# Call a method that returns a value every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I want to call a method which returns a value every few seconds. 
I have tried using a `Timer` with `elapsedEventandler`, but the return type of the method is void in this case. I have used the `TimerTask` class to perform the same task in Java.

I want it to be in .NET 2.0 as I'm using Visual Studio 2005.

Below is the program I'm having trouble with. I tried to use an anonymous method, but the value of `response` in this case does not exist outside the anonymous method:

```
public static string Run(string address)
{                     
    string response = "A";
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Elapsed += delegate 
    {                         
        response = callURL(address);
        console.writeln(response);
        // The actual response value is printed here                
    };          
    t.Interval = 3000;
    t.Start();                      
    Console.WriteLine("response string is " + response);
    // response string is A

    return response;
}

public static string callURL(string address)
{
    className sig = new ClassName(); 
    String responseBody = sig.getURL(address);

    return responseBody;
}
```

How do I get the value of `response` in the `Run` method and send it to the caller of the `Run` method?

Comment: Return it to *where*?  The timer can kick off your method, but no one will be invoking it directly to receive it's result.

Comment: Is it invoke this method every 5 seconds, or only invoke it every 5 seconds after returning? I.E, can invocations stack if they take too long?

Comment: @james: it returns to the caller from another class.

Comment: @DanielA.White: what do you mean by a method can only return twice

Comment: The main point I think you're missing, though, is that the other class has already released control of the method.  The timer runs on a different thread.

Comment: @Bharath - i meant once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have your caller give the class with the timer a callback delegate to pass back the value.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public static void Run(string address, Action<string> callback)
    {                     
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Elapsed += delegate {                         
            var response = callURL(address);

            callback(response);
        };          
        t.Interval = 3000;
        t.Start();
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public void ProcessResponse(string response)
    {
         // do whatever you want here to handle the response...
         // you can write it out, store in a queue, put in a member, etc.
    }

    public void StartItUp()
    {
         YourClass.Run("http://wwww.somewhere.net", ProcessResponse);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: If you want the caller (`OtherClass`) to be able to cancel the timer, you could simply change from an `Action<string>` to a `Func<string, bool>` and have the caller (`OtherClass`) return a bool on whether to stop the timer or not...

```
public class YourClass
{
    public static void Run(string address, Func<string, bool> callback)
    {                     
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Elapsed += delegate {                         
            var response = callURL(address);

            // if callback returns false, cancel timer
            if(!callback(response))
            {
                t.Stop();
            }
        };          
        t.Interval = 3000;
        t.Start();
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public bool ProcessResponse(string response)
    {
         // do whatever you want here to handle the response...
         // you can write it out, store in a queue, put in a member, etc.
         // check result to see if it's a certain value...
         // if it should keep going, return true, otherwise return false
    }

    public void StartItUp()
    {
         YourClass.Run("http://wwww.somewhere.net", ProcessResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow james michael hare.. that was quick and awesome. thank you. :)

Comment: Anytime!  You'll still have to write the code to handle your responses, of course, but that at least gives you the framework...

Comment: i was so lost from yesterday. The rest should not be a problem i guess. this was the main thing. i was trying to convert code from java to c#. and i was so lost here.

Comment: one quick question. how do i stop the timer inside the anonymous method?

Comment: @Bharath: when do you want to stop it?  Do you want to stop it after the first item?  After you retrieve a particular result?  After X minutes?

Comment: yes.. i have to stop it after i get a particular result.
also, is it possible to stop it after X minutes. ex: when i do not get any response?

Comment: Thank you so much James. you made my day a lot shorter today.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Thread` and make the thread call the method you want and give a sleep time to the thread for 5 seconds:

```
Thread loopThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.MainLoop));
loopThread.Start();

private void MainLoop()
{
     while(true)
     {
         // Do stuff
         Thread.Sleep(5000);
     }
}
```

Comment: is it not possible to do it using Timers? i want the method called by the thread, in this case MainLoop to return a value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an insomniac, I hate Sleep() :-)

Comment: using Threads is a cleaner way, as you will not halt your whole system with timers ?

Comment: @James: Thank you sir, after doing a bit of research and this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091710/c-sharp-timer-or-thread-sleep. I agree Timmers are useful in some places as in this case